# how to implement client and server code in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a small chatting App in `Java SE` for `Desktop`, I want to implement the same for `Web` as well, I have `ChatServer` as :

```
public class ChatServer extends Thread {
public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 6035;


public static String initServer() {
    String msg = "";
    int port = DEFAULT_PORT;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        msg = "Listening on port " + port;
        while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            /*System.out.println("Connection receive from "
                    + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());*/
            ChatHandler handler = new ChatHandler(socket);
            handler.start();
        }


    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java ChatServer [port]");
        System.err.println("Where options include:");
        System.err.println("\tport the port on which to listen.");
        msg = "Usage: java ChatServer [port]";
        System.exit(0);
    } finally {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return msg;
}
}
```

Now to call this in `index.jsp`, I have :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%=pkj.com.lenvel.ChatServer.initServer() %></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code is not showing any message and I'm still confused, where to implement code for `Client`?

Comment: what do you mean by client? the client is your browser

Comment: I'm in doubt that you should create a socket within a JSP. Can you create a single class that handles all the connection?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Server (YourServer.java)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class YourServer
{    
    public static void main(String[] args ) 
    {
        try {    
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8765);

            Socket insocket = socket.accept( );

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new 
                InputStreamReader(insocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (insocket.getOutputStream(), 
                true);

            String instring = in.readLine();
            out.println("The server got this: " + instring);
            insocket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {} 
     } 
}
```

**Client.Jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*, java.net.*" %>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Creating Client/Server Applications</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
        <BODY>
        <H1>Creating Client/Server Applications</H1>
        <% 
        try{
            int character;
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8765);
            InputStream inSocket = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outSocket = socket.getOutputStream();
            String str = "Hello!\n";
            byte buffer[] = str.getBytes();
            outSocket.write(buffer);
            while ((character = inSocket.read()) != -1) {
                out.print((char) character);
            }
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(java.net.ConnectException e){
        %>
            You must first start the server application 
            (YourServer.java) at the command prompt.
        <%
        }
        %>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

[Taken from this link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0360__JSP/CreatingClientServerApplications.htm)

Comment: First of All `Thank you very much`, now on more thing I wanna ask is how to `execute` the class containing `main()` on `Apache Tomcat Server`?

Comment: if you are using eclipse, right click on yourserver.java and run it as an application, that's all.

Comment: OK, but What I'm trying to ask actually is `I have a free hosting server on the Net which is Apache Tomcat Server`, now how can I run that server.

Comment: run it as a simple java program by command prompt. 
steps ,
javac YourServer.java ,
java YourServer