# how to execute java class containing main() on Tomcat/openshift

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, openshift

I'm at early stage of developing a Chatting web app in Java, hosted at Openshift.com, searched for how to implement a Client/Server logic in my code and found [Q about Client Server in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930480/how-to-implement-client-and-server-code-in-jsp), that was a good point for me to get stated.

```
public class Server
{    
public static void main(String[] args ) 
{
    try {    
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8765);

        Socket insocket = socket.accept( );

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new 
            InputStreamReader(insocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (insocket.getOutputStream(), 
            true);

        String instring = in.readLine();
        out.println("The server got this: " + instring);
        insocket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {} 
 } 
}
```

but now I want to know How to run `Server.java` on the Apache Tomcat Server, is there any alternate way to implement Server logic or how to make the above code for server to work for me? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't really without doing silly things. What's wrong with running it as a plain Java app.?

Answer (score 2):

The main method, afaik, does not get executed when run inside of a servlet container or application server, it is the entry point for the class (or application) when running via command line.  You need to research writing web applications in java, as it seems you are most familiar with writing command line applications or single classes.  Also, if you listen on port 8765 on openshift, you will not be able to reach that port from the outside.  If you really want to do what you are trying to do there on openshift, you should use the DIY cartridge, remove the default ruby script that is running, and run your class there (and listen on port 8080) and see if it works for you.

Comment: OK I have found a [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122969/java-tcp-server-program-running-on-apache-tomcat), but I'm unable to figure that out correctly

Comment: You need to add the code to the git repository for the DIY application (as either the .class file or a .jar archive) and then setup an action_hook to run it when you do a git push.